# Checking to see if NSUserDefaults was used in an older version of the app

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, nsuserdefaults

I have an app that was developed in Obj C a few years ago. I used NSUserDefaults to create the data to display like so:

```
 NSUserDefaults *userData = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if ([userData objectForKey:@"personDataArray"]==nil)
    {
        mutableDataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    else
    {
        // get the array back out of NSUserDefaults
        NSArray *tempArray = [userData objectForKey:@"personDataArray"];
        //  NSLog(@"The count in the temp saved data is %lu", (unsigned long)tempArray.count);

        // look for any NSData objects in my temp array
        for (NSData *personData in tempArray)
        {
            // set a instance of the person class to each NSData object found in the temp array
            GD_Owed_Person *personObject = [[GD_Owed_Person alloc] init];
            personObject = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:personData];
            //  NSLog(@"CHECK ON THE ARRAY %@", personObject.personsBillsArray);
            [mutableDataArray addObject:personObject];
        }
    }
```

The name of the default is personDataArray.

In the new version of the app (Swift 3) I am looking to use those old defaults. The issue I am having is when I check to see if those defaults are even present I get false back.

```
print(UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey:"personDataArray"))
```

Here are my steps that produce false for the print statement above.

1. Download app from the app store on testing iPhone.
2. Input some user data and save.
3. Run the new app via Xcode on the testing iPhone.
4. New App installs and updates old app.
5. Print returns false when I check for personDataArray inside NSUserDefaults

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value for key `personDataArray` is an array which is an object not a `Bool`

The Swift equivalent is

```
var dataArray = [GD_Owed_Person]()

if let tempArray = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey:"personDataArray") as? [Data] {
    for personData in tempArray {
        let personObject = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with:personData) as! GD_Owed_Person 
        dataArray.append(personObject)
    }
}
```

Please, do not use snake case (GD_Owed_Person) in Swift, use camel case (GDOwedPerson)

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong:

```
print(UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey:"personDataArray"))
```

The right way is as you did in code above:

```
if ([userData arrayForKey:@"personDataArray"]==nil) {
     print("false")
} else {
     print("true")
}
```

I guess you have a problem here too (try arrayForKey):

```
NSArray *tempArray = [userData arrayForKey:@"personDataArray"];
```